# Triggering a javascript function every two hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension. I need to trigger a javascript function every two hours. It is possible to do it with;

```
.setInterval(function(){

...

},time);
```

But I read about setInterval(,) and some of the developers have the opinion that 'using setInterval is bad for browser optimization'. On the other hand, I just need one trigger. I mean, I won't use it frequently. Would you advice me to continue with setInterval or is there any other way to create time based events which won't make the browser cry ?

Comment: Show proof that setTimeout is bad for browser optomizartion. I think thats wrong.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have miswritten. I meant to say 'using setInterval is bad". [Here is a jsFiddle that supports the idea](http://jsfiddle.net/mayoung/Ctg8C/)

Comment: Yes for that case isnt a good idea. You could still use a global to tell if you are executing the callback and skip those interval instances

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're asking about a Chrome extension, you can use `chrome.alarms` API to do it. Do note you need the `"alarms"` permission.

```
chrome.alarms.create("my2hoursAlarm", {periodInMinutes: 120});

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
  switch(alarm.name) {
    case "my2hoursAlarm":
      // Do stuff
      break;
  }
});
```

The upside of using Chrome alarms is that they work well with [Event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages). If your extension is not doing much and is okay with being completely unloaded between those events, `chrome.alarms` will wake your extension while `setInterval` will be wiped by the unload.

The only downside of Chrome alarms is that it can't be fired faster than once a minute. In that case you want to use `setInterval` anyway - and not use Event pages.